# How to set initially selected option in select control with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Please could I ask for help with the following:

I have a select control defined as below and I populate it's options with strings from an array of strings in my component called tools.Attributes.Serials It works fine:

```
<select class="noBorder additionalSelectStyle" name="filter_for" (change)="OnSerialChanged($event.target)">
            <option *ngFor = 'let serial of tools.Attributes.Serials'>
                {{serial}}
            </option>
        </select>
```

The displayed list will show the first item as the selected one.

Say I have a variable in my component's .ts code called nMyIndex = 1.

What code do I need to bind to nMyIndex so that the list appears with item 1 as default rather than item 0?

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it, working now. Need to use as shown in following code snippet:

```
; let i = index' [selected]="i == nMyIndex"
```

Comment: Really you should use `[(ngModel)]` -or ReactiveForms- to make a binding between a variable in .ts and a input (or select) in the .html, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngModel)

Comment: yes, that would be neater. For example, say I have variables in my .ts like so: public m_array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
  public m_selectedValue = "two"; then I can bind the selected element to a <select> element like so: <select [(ngModel)]="m_selectedValue">

        <option *ngFor = 'let num of m_array; let i = index'>
            {{num}}
        </option>

    </select> But how could I do the same thing but with a numeric variable of value 1 rather than a string variable of value of "two"

Comment: In my previous comment I meant to delete the "let i = index" as it is not used.

Comment: you can use `<option [value]="i+1">` -or `<option [ngValue]="i+1"`>, or if you has an array of object with id and name,  `<option [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>`